# How can I invert the pass/fail status column in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a table as:

```
sid   sname   status
101    abc    pass
102    cda    fail
103    fgh    pass
104    hij    pass
105    jqk    fail
106    lfj    fail
```

and I want a output as:

```
sid   sname   status
101    abc    fail
102    cda    pass
103    fgh    fail
104    hij    fail
105    jqk    pass
106    lfj    pass
```

Comment: just negate status using a case statement

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    sid, 
    sname,
    case
        when status = 'pass' then 'fail'
        when status = 'fail' then 'pass'
        else null
    end as 'status'
from tableX
```

Comment: `when status = 'fail' then 'pass'
        else null` redundant.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: the `else null` is redundant but does no harm and is explicit, and being explicit is good.

Comment: @brykneval: updating a table isn't 'a output'; you get an output from a query.  If the OP wants to update the question to say "I want to UPDATE the table so that the status column is inverted", then that's a legitimate (though slightly different) request.  But as it stands, 'an output' is reasonably interpreted as 'the output of a query'.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table
SET Status = CASE Status WHEN 'pass' THEN 'fail' ELSE 'pass' END
GO
SELECT *
FROM Table
GO
```

Or:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Gender = IIF(Gender = 'pass', 'fail', 'pass')
GO
SELECT *
FROM Table
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  FYI: to enter code as `code`, type it into the edit box, then select it, then push the **`{}`** button above the box to indent it all by 4 spaces.  Avoid tabs; they complicate things.

Comment: The problem with your first `CASE` statement is that if there are any rows with a NULL status, they become `pass` rows.  This might be what's desired (if, indeed, an UPDATE is required at all; I interpreted it like MacGyver did as a query, not an UPDATE), but it might not.  Similarly, I wonder what the `IIF` version does with rows containing a NULL status?  Note that `...SET status = CASE status WHEN 'fail' THEN 'pass' ELSE 'fail' END` yields a different result when there are any rows with a NULL status.